# Setting var to sum of two textbox values is 0, how come?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am experiencing something odd, please see below. Why is alert 1 outputting 0 but alert 2 outputting the correct sum? They are set to the same thing...

```
var sumTotal = parseFloat($('#tb1').val()) + parseFloat($('#tb2').val());
//tb1.val() == 3, tb2.val() == 5;    

1) alert(sumTotal); //Outputs 0;
2) alert(parseFloat($('#tb1').val()) + parseFloat($('#tb2').val())); //Outputs 8;
```

Exact code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var koh = 1;
        var sumTotal = parseFloat($('#tb1').val()) + parseFloat($('#tb2').val());
        window.setInterval(function () {
            // correct value
            tb3.val(parseFloat($('#tb1').val()) + parseFloat($('#tb2').val())); 
            tb3.val(parseFloat(sumTotal)); // 0
            tb3.val(sumTotal); // 0
            tb3.val(koh++) //increments +1
        }, 2500);
    })
```

since koh increments +1 can this still be a scoping issue?

Comment: is `sumTotal` being defined at a different time as opposed to the second alert expression's run time?

Comment: are you sure that sumTotal is in scope when the alert is reached?

Comment: I tested in Firefox and got alerted 8 for both #1 and #2

Comment: My HTML code: <input type="text" id="tb1"></input>
<input type="text" id="tb2"></input>
<a id="link" href="#">Test</a>

My JS code:
$("#link").click(function(){
    var sumTotal = parseFloat($('#tb1').val()) + parseFloat($('#tb2').val());
    alert(sumTotal);
    alert(parseFloat($('#tb1').val()) + parseFloat($('#tb2').val()));
    return false;
});

Comment: I have added the code i am using. tb3 is a textbox i am outputting to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sumTotal is calculated before the values of the text boxes have changed.  If they default to 0, the result will be 0, and it won't change even if the text boxes' values do.

If they default to blank, sumTotal is NaN -- and it still won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the call to `parseFloat`, so this line

```
tb3.val(parseFloat(sumTotal));
```

becomes

```
tb3.val(sumTotal);
```

In fact, `sumTotal` is already a float (you've converted it before summing):

```
var sumTotal = parseFloat($('#tb1').val()) + parseFloat($('#tb2').val());
```

and using `parseFloat` on a float value will probably lead to undefined behaviour.

---

I think I spotted it: the value in the textboxes is prepopulated in html?

If the textboxes are empty or contain 0 at this point

```
var sumTotal = parseFloat($('#tb1').val()) + parseFloat($('#tb2').val());
```

the value stored in sumTotal will be NaN or 0 respectively (thanks to cHao for pointing this out) and it won't change from then on: remember that the statement `tb3.val(sumTotal);` won't re-evaluate `sumTotal`.

If you wanted to update the sum on user input you'll need something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sumTotal = parseFloat($('#tb1').val()) + parseFloat($('#tb2').val());
    $('#tb1').add('#tb2').keyup(function () {
        sumTotal = parseFloat($('#tb1').val()) + parseFloat($('#tb2').val());
        tb3.val(sumTotal);
    });
})
```

Comment: opps. yeah i had it without, i tried adding it to see if it helped. It made no difference either way.

Comment: Empty strings become NaN when parsed as floats.

Comment: cHao, it seems we had the same idea. By the way, thank you for pointing this out.